# How to make radio button read only in runtime

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a radio button which i have created programatically and in some condition i need to make this radio button to read only. I also tried RadioButton.IsEnable = false; but after that  nothing is showing in my app it is looking like visibility.Collapsed of my radio button.

This code i am using for create radio button:

```
 RadioButton radbtn = new RadioButton();
                radbtn.Name = choicelist[ctr].ID;
                radbtn.Content = choicelist[ctr].Name;
                radbtn.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                radbtn.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
```

I want to set this radio button as read only.

Comment: How do you add the button to the UI ? I don't see why "IsEnable = false" would not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI i found the solution for this and it works for me.

```
radbtn.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```